# How to make number automatically in the Constructor java

Tags: java, oop, constructor, static

I got two constructors :

```
private int num ;
private Room room ;
private boolean status;
private E_types type ;
```

1- : Partial Constructor :

```
Instrument(int num)
Partial Constructor ~ use for initial key fields
```

2- : Full Constructor :

```
Instrument(Room room, boolean status, E_Types type)
Full Constructor ~ use for initial all fields instruments should be numbered automatically
```

What is this automatically numbered ?

Thanks :)

Comment: From where did you get this code ?

Comment: *"What is this automatically numbered?"* You'll have to ask whoever gave you the assignment what they mean by that. We could *guess*, but they'll *know*.

Comment: I guess they meant by 'automatically numbered', there default or initial values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `static` variable in the class that will increase automatically with each Instrument created. To explain simply what `static` means: It's a variable together for all the instances of a class. Let it assign to `num`.

```
public class Instrument {
    private static int id = 0; // representing ID
    private int num = 0;
    private Room room ;
    private boolean status;
    private E_types type ;

    public Instrument(Room room, boolean status, E_Types type) {
        Instrument.id++;
        this.num = Instrument.id;
        this.room = room;
        this.status = status;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static int getID() {
        return Instrument.id;
    }

    public int getNum() {
       return this.num;
    }
}
```

---

Let's try it on an example. Let's create 4 Instruments on base of the constructor above and call the getter and the static method returning the max ID.

```
Instrument a = new Instrument(...);
Instrument b = new Instrument(...);
Instrument c = new Instrument(...);
Instrument d = new Instrument(...);

System.out.println(c.getNum()); // prints 3, num of "c" instrument
System.out.println(Instrument.getID()); // prints 4 (total of instruments)
```

Comment: Thank you , I tried this and it works !
so, we need to use static when we need something shared to all the objects ? right ?